# Show that the functional is continuous everywhere in $V$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $J: V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional and $V$ a linear space with norm.

Show that if $J$ is continuous on $0 \in V$ then $J$ is continuous everywhere in $V$.

That's what I have tried:

Let $y_n \in V, n=1,2, \dots$.

$J$ is continuous on $0 \in V$.

That means that if $||y_n-0|| \to 0$ then $|J(y_n)-J(0)| \to 0$.

$V$ is a linear space, so $J(0)=0$.

How could we continue? Could we set $y_n=y_1-y_2$?

Or what else could we do?

Comment: *Hint:* $|J(x)-J(y)|=|J(x-y)|$. If $x$ is close to $y$, then $x-y$ is close to $0$.

Comment: So do we have to suppose an $\epsilon>0$ and find a $\delta$ such that if $||x-y||< \delta$ then $|J(x)-J(y)|< \epsilon$?
$$$$
Or do we have to  do something else? @LeBtz

Comment: That's exactly what you have to do.

Comment: Is it right as follows? @LeBtz
$$$$
Suppose $\epsilon>0$. We are looking for a $\delta>0$ such that if $||x-y||< \delta, x,y \in V$ then $|J(x)-J(y)|< \epsilon (1)$.
$$$$

$$||x-y||< \delta \text{ implies that } ||x-y|| \to 0$$.

So we have that $|J(x-y)| \to 0 \Rightarrow |J(x)-J(y)| \to 0$.

The above means that $|J(x)-J(y)|< \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Idea is right but not executed correctly. For $\epsilon>0$ we find $\delta >0$ s.t. if $\|z-0\|<\delta$ then $|J(z)-0| <\epsilon$. Hence for all $x,y$ with $\|x-y\|<\delta$ we have $|J(x)-J(y)| = |J(x-y)| <\epsilon$

Comment: @LeBtz So we set $z=x-y$, right? And how can we be sure that $z$ can be a written as the difference of two numbers?

Comment: @LeBtz So is the following answer complete? $$$$
For $\epsilon>0$ we find $\delta>0$ such that if $||z-0||< \delta$ then $|J(z)-0|< \epsilon$.
$$$$
We choose $x,y \in V$ such that $x-y=z$. So we have that if $||x-y||< \delta$ then $|J(x-y)|=|J(x)-J(y)|< \epsilon$.
$$$$
Thus $J$ is continuous everywhere in $V$.

Comment: No, it is not. Because as i said, you chose $x,y$ first and then just let $z= x-y$ you dont choose $x,y$ dependent on z. Actually my answer above was a complete proof..

Comment: So since $||z||< \delta \Rightarrow |J(z)|< \epsilon$ for any $z \in V$, it holds also for $z=x-y$, right?

Comment: This is correct now!

Comment: @LeBtz Isn't it better to organize your comments and put it all in an answer? This way OP can accept it and the question goes out of the unanswered queue. :)

Comment: @IvoTerek Ok, I did so. At first I didn't want to provide a full answer. I thought that it should be possible to deduce an own one by using my hint. Sadly this wasn't the case.

Comment: It happens!  ${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in V$, $\epsilon > 0$. Since $J$ ist continuous in $0$, there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $\|z\|<\delta \implies |J(z)| = |J(z)-J(0)| < \epsilon$.

For $y\in V$ with $\|x-y\| < \delta$, it follows that $|J(x)-J(y)| = |J(x-y)| < \epsilon$. Hence $J$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Does the following also hold? $$$$
If J is continuous on $x \in V$ then $J$ is continuous everywhere in $V$?
$$$$
If so, how could we prove this?